# Squid reverse proxy single domain SSL

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, amazon-cloudfront, squid

Trying to setup squid to cache content from our AWS Cloudfront distribution

media.ourdomain.com is a CNAME for our Cloudfront distribution

Squid configuration snippet (using 3.5.6)

> https_port 443 accel no-vhost defaultsite=media.ourwebsite.com
>   cert=/var/squid/certs/media.ourwebsite.com.crt
>   key=/var/squid/certs/media.ourwebsite.com.key
>
> cache_peer media.ourwebsite.com parent 443 0 no-query originserver ssl
>   name=ourwebsite forceddomain=media.ourwebsite.com
>
> acl ourwebsite_1 dstdomain media.ourwebsite.com
>   cache_peer_access ourwebsite allow ourwebsite_1
>   http_access allow ourwebsite_1

Squid throws this error when attempting to connect to the cache peer

> Handshake with SSL server failed: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

This is reproducible with

> $ openssl s_client -connect media.ourwebsite.com:443
>   error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Adding the -servername flag to s_client fixes the problem

> $ openssl s_client -connect media.ourwebsite.com:443 -servername media.ourwebsite.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: You should probably show your code rather than troubleshooting commands. Use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). `-servername` is SNI, so now we need to see your code to tell you how to fix it. You also seem to have some DNS issues with `ourdomain.com` and `ourwebsite.com`. Also see Jarmoc's [SSL Interception Proxies and Transitive Trust](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-eu-12/Jarmoc/bh-eu-12-Jarmoc-SSL_TLS_Interception-Slides.pdf).